# Can I use one socket to manage more then one window?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, socket.io

I'm starting to use socket.io, I'm developing a very simple chat that connect the user to nodejs server. I have the chat on www.exmaple.com/chat.html, my question is:

can I only use ONE socket with an user that will open the chat in many windows?

I mean...

Like Facebook, if I open more tabs I can see the message of my friend in all the windows.

So I have to do the **same thing**, but I don't want to open a socket in each window, but only one for all...is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can,and you can handle it by putting proper tags in messages,
the tags show the message belongs to which window or which user ...

see this link to create javascript singletone class [HOW TO WRITE A SINGLETON CLASS IN JAVASCRIPT](http://www.javascriptkata.com/2009/09/30/how-to-write-a-singleton-class-in-javascript/)

Comment: hmmm no one moment... the problem is....How the other windows can hadle the messages if they are not connected to the server?

Comment: I would only connect ONE windows and the other receive it automatically

Comment: you can create a static class that handles message traffic in client side the class shod have a event named OnMessageReceived, other window should Handle this event ,every time a  message receives the event will be fired and all window will be aware and if messages belongs to them can process it

Comment: yes correct... i want to do it...but how can I "share" a js class that connect ONLY one time to the server?...and then share the message to all the windows/pages? thanks

Comment: @DeveloperX I have seen the link you gave me, but does it work on different pages/windows? I Mean...if i call that class from different pages can i check if an object has been inizialized before?